UNSUPPORTED_API_VERSION: Invalid Api version specified on URL on Manifest Retrieval
After refreshing a sandbox last night, I was unable to retrieve metadata from the org using SFDX in VSCode due to a mismatch in API Versions. The error received was:
15:51:26.514 Starting SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org

UNSUPPORTED_API_VERSION: Invalid Api version specified on URL

After some digging, I combined a few almost decade old SE and Trailblazer community answers to fix it. At first I just reset the API Version to 60.0, but then I received the following:
16:00:54.755 Starting SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org


16:00:59.767 ended SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org

with no specified error, just that the retrieval was failing according to the VSCode popup. Solution in first comment in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

To fix:
Run the command sf update  to make sure the CLI is updated.
Run the command sfdx force:config:set org-api-version=60.0 to set the API version back to 60.
Run the command sf org logout --target-org YOUR_NAME@ORGANIZATION.com.SANDBOX to force logout your user.
Quit VSCode and reopen.
CMD/CTRL+SHIFT+P and SFDX: Authorize an Org for your org again.
Make sure the API version in your package.xml and sfdx-project.json are 60.0. Retrieve manifest.
